# Azure Function Facebook Auth Scopes

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I'm using Facebook authentication for my Azure Function, auth works great and the function works.  When it was configured I was asked what scopes I would like, such as "email", "likes" etc.  How do I get a reference to the scopes from within my function?

I have a session cookie, not sure if I need to use that somehow.  The documentation on this seems a little thin on the ground.

Nick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I just discovered from this URL,

https://cgillum.tech/2016/03/07/app-service-token-store/

There is an endpoint on my Azure Function at

".auth/me"

This returns a bunch of JSON with my Facebook scopes in, at least some anyway.

Sorted!

Unless someone can add anything?

Comment: Okay, not good, this doesn't actually work on the server, I can run the request locally, with the cookie, works great, in an another azure function, it doesn't work, it throws a 401 unauthorised error.

Comment: Just for reference in this thread,

ClaimsPrincipal cp = ClaimsPrincipal.Current;

That gets you your currently authenticated Facebook user.